# Codeigniter redirects in __remap method in My_Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

i am using this remap method in My_Controller with philsturgeon's library

```
<?php
class MY_Controller extends MX_Controller 
{
    protected $data;
    protected $view;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _remap($method, $parameters)
    {
        if($this->view === TRUE OR $this->view === '')
        {
            $this->template->build('default');
        }else if(strlen($this->view) > 0){
            $this->template->build($this->view);
        }else{
            $checkpoint =   $this->session->flashdata('exit');
            if($checkpoint){
                exit();
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('exit',TRUE);
            }
            $this->redirect = base_url()  . $this->redirect;
            redirect($this->redirect);
        }   

    }
}
```

Here i want to know in the child controller what i do to handle this situation

```
<?php
class Home extends My_Controller {

    public  $redirect = '/admin/dashboard';
    public  $view   =   FALSE;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function dashboard($days = '')
    {
        if (!$this->session->userdata('session_admin'))
        {
            $this->redirect =   '/admin/login';
        }else{
            //display dashboard 
        }
    }

    function login()
    {   
        if ($this->session->userdata('session_user')){
            $this->redirect;
        }else{
            $this->view =   'login';    //Load login view through remap method with template library
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it comes in a loop and exits at my condition in the My_Controller. Although i have created this but i want to know how to handle redirects here. What should be the optimized solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably not the answer, but in the `login()` function, this looks slightly wrong? `if ($this->session->userdata('session_user')){
            $this->redirect;
        }else{` The `$this->redirect;` will do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue using flash data i am setting flash data. When it comes in the loop it checks for the flash message if it exists use exit otherwise set flash data.